# Unable to run telegraf docker container with inputs.mqtt_consumer

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, mosquitto, telegraf

I am unable to run telegraf as a docker container with the input `[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]`

I set the most basic config, as follows :

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
servers = ["tcp://localhost:1883"]
topics = [
    "#"
  ]
data_format = "json"
```

I am using Mosquitto. It works if I run telegraf following the instructions in the influxDB GUI, under Load Data > Telegraf. I can indeed see on InfluxDB the list of topics published.

```
telegraf --config http://localhost:8086/api/v2/telegrafs/{id}
```

I get the following log :

```
[inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connected [tcp://127.0.0.1:1883]
```

However, if I try to run that same config as a docker container, it doesn't work. I get the following error message :

```
[telegraf] Error running agent: starting input inputs.mqtt_consumer: network Error : dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1883: connect: connection refused
```

I don't understand what's missing. The problem obviously has to do with some settings related to the servers address. I tried names other than localhost in the servers array : 127.0.0.1, and some funny names like "mosquitto".

I don't have any other logs to show. There is nothing logged in `/tmp/metrics.out`, nothing in `/var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Docker on Windows or a Mac, `localhost` resolves to the Docker container that's referencing it and not to the computer it's running on or other containers running on that computer. Unless Mosquitto is running inside that container, `localhost` won't get you to it.

If Mosquitto is running in another container, you'll need to use the name or address of the network port of that container. If it's running directly on the computer that the Telegraf Docker container is running on, you can use `host.docker.internal`.

There are other more complicated ways to set up Docker networking that might also resolve this problem, but the simplest thing is to use the correct name or IP address for wherever Mosquitto is running, and `localhost` most likely is not that, as you've seen.

Also remember that `127.0.0.1` is synonymous with `localhost` - it also means "the same computer", which in the case of a container, at least on macOS and Windows, means "the same container".